# Laravel Eloquent ORM seemed to be easy

Tags: php, database, laravel, orm, eloquent

I try to connect table with ORM.
I have a 'Customers' table and 'Contacts'.

In my models I have write this :

```
class Customer extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $softDelete = true;
    protected $guarded = array();


    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Contact');
    }

}
```

and this

```
class Contact extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $softDelete = true;
    protected $guarded = array();

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Customer');
    }

}
```

And in my controller when I try

```
return Customer::find($id)->contacts
```

I have no result :/

What I missing ?

Thank you

Comment: Your code looks fine, perhaps some problems with the data itself? So perhaps in DB no correctly linked contacts for this customer or perhaps softdeleted records.

Comment: Database Contacts = | customer_id | name | ...
Database Customers = | name | phone | ... (without contact_id)

You think softdeleting can generate a problem?

Comment: But how about the data?
are there actually contact records with the specified customer id. and are they perhaps softdeleted? try running `Customer::find($id)->contacts()->withTrashed()->get()`

Comment: I think my database is ok? http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/2463/hp12.png

Comment: Customer::find($id)->contacts()->withTrashed()->get() have no result.
I'm gonna be crazy! ^^

Answer (score 0):

My Bad!

Ma database seeder save seed 140 customers and 35 contacts.
I try to get the 140th contact...

My code works perfectly